# Prestashop 1.7.1 - Online Chat

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have purchased module [Online Chat](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/support-online-chat/22666-online-chat.html)

Module works fine when I work as SuperAdmin, but I would like a regular user (for example user with logistics profile) the ability to enable/disable chat and administer the conversations.

Is that possible? If not, which other module shall be used? Thanks

Comment: Actually you should contact the developper of the module for making him work on this subject. It might be more relevant than asking here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matt. Developer has been already contacted but it is extremely relevant to ask it here as I want unbiased feedback from Prestashop community. I am sure somebody else has faced this issue.

Comment: If I understood, you should set the permission for that admin profile in "permission tab" in the backoffice...

Comment: I found that I had to enable that module for that specific user.